# Help to understand a passage on a proof ($\|f\|_p\to\|f\|_\infty$).

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

The problem this:

> Assume that $f$ is a complex measurable function on $X$, $\mu$ is a positive measure on $X$, $\|f\|_\infty > 0$ and $\|f\|_r<\infty$ for some $r<\infty$. Prove that $$\|f\|_p\to\|f\|_\infty ~~~\mbox{as}~~~p\to\infty.$$

This is the Exercise 4(e) from Real and Complex Analysis (Rudion), Chapter 3 ($L^p$-Spaces). In the internet, I've found some proofs. One is this:

[image: From internet]

I couldn't understand why one can conclude $\lim_{p\to\infty}\|f\|_p=\infty?$ How can I fix this problem in the proof?

EDIT: Okay, what Frank Lu did justify $\lim_{p\to\infty}\|f\|_p=\infty$. Now I have other question. Since $\|f\|_p\leq \|f\|^{\frac{r}{p}}_r$, one can conclude that $\limsup \|f\|_p\leq 1.$ How can I conclude the equality?

Comment: This is a terribly written proof: $x \in x$, $\lim_{n \to \infty}...$ where no $n$ occurs.

Comment: @TheGeekGreek is is true. thought you could thing about the n as a p ... rsrs

Comment: I am just figuring out what is going on...since if you take the $p$-th root on the inequality, the limit tends not to $\infty$.

Comment: @TheGeekGreek yeap. You can consider $\mu\{|f|>2^p\}>0 \forall p$ but we cannot conclude that $\mu\{|f|>2^p\}^{-1/p}$ has a positive low bound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the idea: Let $t>0$ be any real number, set
$$E_t=\{x\in X: |f(x)|\geq t\}.$$
If you assume that $\|f\|_\infty=+\infty$, then $\mu(E_t)>0$. Then it follows from Chebyshev's inequality that
$$t^p\mu(E_t)\leq\|f\|_p^p\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad t\mu(E_t)^{\frac{1}{p}}\leq\|f\|_p.$$
Now if $\mu(E_t)=\infty$ then we can see that $\|f\|_p=\infty$ for every $p$ thus $\lim_{p\to\infty}\|f\|_p=+\infty$. If $\mu(E_t)<\infty$, then one can see that
$$t\leq\liminf_{p\to\infty}\|f\|_p.$$
Observe that $E_s\subseteq E_t$ whenever $s\geq t$ so in this case $0<\mu(E_s)\leq\mu(E_t)<\infty$, thus by the same argument we can prove that
$$s\leq\liminf_{p\to\infty}\|f\|_p,\quad\forall s\geq t.$$
Therefore $\liminf_{p\to\infty}\|f\|_p=\infty$. Note that here we take $\liminf$ because we don't know whether the limit exist or not.

For the second question, what we want to prove is $\liminf_{p\to\infty}\|f\|_p\geq\|f\|_\infty$. For any $0<t<1$ let $E_t$ be the same as above. Then we have
$$\|f\|_p\geq t\mu(E_t)^{\frac{1}{t}}.$$
If $\mu(E_t)<\infty$ then we see that $\liminf_{p\to\infty}\|f\|_p\geq t$, then let $t\to 1^-$. If $\mu(E_t)=\infty$ then we still have $\liminf_{p\to\infty}\|f\|_p\geq t$. In both cases, we have $\liminf_{p\to\infty}\|f\|_p\geq 1.$

Comment: What is the purpose of the "s" part?

Comment: To show that the liminf is greater than every positive number.

Comment: Thought $t$ already is any positive number... I edited my question and add another one. Can you help me?

Comment: I think in order for the result to hold, the measure space should be $\sigma-$finite. Otherwise it seems not possible to prove the reversed inequality.

Comment: yes, it is possible (I have a proof right here). I'll show to you tomorrow! Thanks for the help.

Comment: You're right, we don't actually need the $\sigma-$finite assumption. I'll add the proof to my answer.

Comment: In the second part, what if $\mu (E_t) =0$?

Comment: That's impossible as $\|f\|_\infty=1$ is assumed.

Comment: Yeah, you toke t<1. One last thing. I think you have to take $t\to 1^-$ instead of $t\to 1^+$

Comment: You are right，that is a typo.